# What is meant by decoration with regards to site scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the FAQ, it says

> Decorating advice.

is outside the scope of the SE. What is meant by this? Does it mean that all questions about projects where the purpose is decoration are off topic, or does it mean that questions about aesthetics are off topic?

For example, would the question

> Is there something that looks like a shoji but is suitable for outdoors use, say to go around an outdoors shower?

be off-topic? (Apologies if the example is hopelessly n00b!)

Answer (score 6):

The way I see it is for advice along the lines:

> What colour will go best in this room?

Which no-one can objectively answer. We don't know what colours you like and all answers will be (potentially) equally valid.

However, your question looks like it might well be on-topic as you are asking for a material that has certain characteristics and must fulfil certain needs.